# Installation guide for SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 OS.

Tags: sharepoint

I need to install SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint server 2010 on windows Vista or Windows 7 OS.

Please provide step by step installation guide.

Answer (score 4):

Minimum Requirement [Only Development Environment Not Production Environment]
Computer OS with an x64-capable CPU, 
At least 2 gigabytes (GB) of RAM to install

Download one only from these two links as per requirement:
A) Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983

B) Microsoft SharePoint Server Standard 2010 Trial 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9344

**Step 1: Install the Prerequisites for SharePoint 2010**

Create a temporary folder named "SharePointFiles" (or whatever you prefer).

Copy the downloaded .exe installer to this folder

Open command prompt and execute the following command:

```
C:\\>SharePointServer.exe /extract :C:\SharePointFiles
```

Inside the same folder locate the config.xml file from the folder SharePointFiles\Files\Setup

Open it into NotePad and Modify the config.xml

Add the following tag inside the configuration section:

```
<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>
```

Run the Setup.cmd file.

**Step 2: Installation of SharePoint 2010**

SharePoint Server installation dialog will open.

First use the Install Pre-requisites option to install the required components.

Next use the Install SharePoint Server option to continue.

Now the following new screen is prompted.

Enter the following key for trial edition: `VK7BD-VBKWR-6FHD9-Q3HM9-6PKMX`. Or Get Trail edition Key from MSDN official site:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9344

Click Accept and Continue.

Use the Standalone option to install all the SharePoint components in your machine.

Wait for around 10 minutes, the installation will get completed click the close button.

**Step 3: Open SharePoint Products & Run in browser**
A) After the installation you will be able to see the following start menu item:

Go to "Start menu" > "All Program Files" and open up "Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products" folder.

B) Open the SharePoint 2010 Central Administration item and you will get the following prompt:

Enter the your `machine name` and `password`.

C) Now SharePoint  2010 Central Administration opens.

**Optional Steps :**

**Step 4: Install Visual Studio 2010 and Developer Documentation**

Install Visual Studio 2010.
Download and install the Microsoft SharePoint 2010 SDK.
Pls refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

**Step 5: Create Hyper-V Images from Your Installed System** 
Pls refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

Comment: "Add the following tag inside the configuration section:" Did you missed out anything here?

Comment: I found it somewhere else:
<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>